# ASP.NET Identity UserID primary key to be foreign key and primary key in your custom table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using AspNetIdentity tables and I have custom table for customer profile. I would like the key of `Customer Profile` table to be same as `AspnetUser` table. Is this possible?

I would like strUserID that is a column in the `AspNetUser` table to be primary key and foreign key for `Customer Profile` table. But I get an error

> EntityType 'CustomerProfile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Code:

```
    [Column("strCustomerAddress")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter customer's address.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Column("strCustomerName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter customer's name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("strUserID")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string strUserID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer please? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `[Key]` attribute is on the navigation property instead of `ForeignKey`. So write your `strUserID` as follows:

```
[Key]
[ForeignKey("User")]
public string strUserID { get; set; }

public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Now it will work fine!